# Best way to generate (random) a division which result is not a decimal number

Tags: java, math, random

I have to create a method that generates **randomly 2 numbers**, that divided give as result a number without decimals.
For example:

```
int result = 4 / 2; //is ok
int result = 4 / 3; //is NOT ok
```

I already create a **recursive method** that, when the result is a decimal number, call itself and generates 2 new numbers. But, of course, this is not the best approach since, in theory, I may get as a result a decimal number forever!

Is there a good way to achieve my goal?

Comment: generate the denominator *d*, then a multiplier *k* to get the numerator *n* as *n* = *k* * *d* .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not generate the result and divisor, then multiply both to get the dividend?

Instead of using `4` and `3` as dividend and divisor, which results in a decimal number when divided, multiply them both to get `12` as dividend and `4` as divisor which once divided gives `3`.

Comment: You got the [dividend and divisor](http://www.amathsdictionaryforkids.com/qr/d/division.html) backwards.

Comment: Ouch, math vocabulary is hard lol. Thanks, fixed!

Answer (score 1):

when **numerator/denominator = result**, then **numerator= result x denominator**

then it will be easier to gen result and denominator :)

```
int numerator;
int denominator;
int result;

result= rand.nextInt(5,10);
denominator= rand.nextInt(2,10);
numerator = result * denominator;
```

Comment: you are welcome!!! @MDP